# Java Applet Authentication

Tags: java, applet, passwords

I have Java Applet(J2EE), I want to make it accessible only to a certain set of users,by authenticating them using username and password.What is the the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This [guide](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Security5.html) to form-based authentication could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The way you secure this will depend on what you have on server side?

1. Applet takes username and password. Calls some auth service on the server to authenticate the user.
2. Next challenge would be to maintain this authentication state. Solution would totally depend on how you are communicating back from your applet.